# FileProvider keep sending unsupported attachment

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm working on an app(min SDK is 26) that will share a .CSV file (/storage/emulated/0/Documents/SensorData_Date.csv) to Telegram.

I try to use FileProvider to share a document from my app to Telegram, WhatsApp, Gmail, etc. I use the code below, and when I test the result, my app will redirect me to Telegram, WhatsApp, or Gmail, and then it will not attach the csv file and show "unsupported attachement"

My Code:

== AndroidManifest.xml ==

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.sharefiletest.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/shared_file_path" />
</provider>
```

== shared_file_path.xml ==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/" />
    <external-path name="files_root" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_storage_root" path="." />
</paths>
```

== Code in MainActivity ==

```
private String excel_file_name = "SensorData_Date.csv";
private File FilePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), excel_file_name);

if(FilePath.exists())
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", FilePath);
   ShareFileToOtherApp.setType("text/comma-separated-values");
   ShareFileToOtherApp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   ShareFileToOtherApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share the file ..."));
}
```

== Result ==
Unsupported attachment

I already tried changing setType(), .addFlags(), and changing the manifest file, but all of them returned the same result.

Comment: Please describe what is the issue and what error / output your are getting and what is excepted output

Comment: @Bala I try to use FileProvider to share a document from my app to Telegram, WhatsApp, Gmail, etc. I use the code above, and when I test the result, my app will redirect me to Telegram, WhatsApp, or Gmail, and then it will not attach the csv file and show "unsupported attachement". Do you know how to fix it ?